# How to ignore HostnameVerifier or add a custom HostnameVerifier on mule?

Tags: java, spring-security, mule, mule-studio

I need  to ignore HostnameVerifier or add a custom HostnameVerifier on mule flow. Is it possible? (Version 3.7).

This is only for tests, because I use invalid certificates just to simulate the HTTPS enviroment.

Comment: What is `HostnameVerifier`? It's not a Mule class: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=HostnameVerifier

Comment: The reason why you mention is because of the following error I guess.                                                                                                                       org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain execute
WARNING: GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.HostnameVerifierListener.onFailure(HostnameVerifierListener.java:56)                                                                        Are you trying to test HTTPS by creating a client in for the listner ?